# ¿Como mostrar en pantalla el número total de los usuarios en c++?

Tags: c++, clase, herencia, vectores

Se me dispone de las clases auxiliares: Dirección y Fecha junto con la clase Asistente hereda desde la Clase Persona y la clase Artista hereda desde la Clase Persona.

Lo que se tiene que hacer es mostrar en la pantalla el numero total de asistentes, el codigo no lo pondre aqui ya que son mas de 100 usuarios pero adjuntare una parte de estos para que se pueda apreciar los datos que tienen.

```
RUT;DV;NOMBRES;PATERNO;MATERNO;NAC_DIA;NAC_MES;NAC_ANHO;DIRECCION;NRO;COMUNA;TIPO_ENTRADA;EVENTO_DD;EVENTO_MM;EVENTO_AA;OCUPADA

19635898;3;Katherine;Hodges;Fernandez;3;12;2007;AYSEN;3057;SAN JOAQUIN;1;19;3;2022;1
16751926;7;Viviana Estephania;Pavez;Quinteros;21;1;1975;NONATO COO;2228;PUENTE ALTO;2;18;8;2022;1
22352957;9;María Antonia de Monserrat;Vásquez;Donoso;27;11;1982;TOME;3645;PUENTE ALTO;1;20;1;2022;1
16741104;4;Nicolás Hernán;Catalán;Narvaez;6;5;1986;CRISTOBAL COLON;1428;LAS CONDES;3;19;3;2022;1
```

Si esta es la cantidad de personas que se ponen en un archivo.txt el programa necesita contar la cantidad y después mostrarla en la consola, he intentado hacer esto y no he conseguido hacerlo de manera eficiente, algo de ayuda me vendría genial.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cada línea es un usuario? Si es así, cuenta las líneas y listo.

Comment: Cada linea es un usuario, pero si es como tu dices como podría contar las lineas? Nunca he hecho algo por el estilo.

Comment: Para contar líneas, abre el archivo con un flujo de datos de entrada desde archivo (`std::ifstream`) y lee líneas (`std::getline`) hasta agotar el contenido.